# Java(Android): Find unused classes

Tags: java, android, removeclass

In my Android application, I am using lot of **open source JAVA libraries** as source. It makes the application very huge in size.

Number of `classes` coming around **6000+**. I want to remove the `unused classes` from it. Any one have idea about how to do it. I find many tools, but that is for removing unused codes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Main thing is I want to use ProGuard, but cant able to build with it. I am getting GC overhead limit exceeded and Java heap space error when trying to build with ProGuard due to huge app size and so many classes.

Comment: I doubt your application is too big, you probably have a low heap space on java. try increasing the maximum space allowed. You can also increase it to beyond what you actually have on your computer, and in most OSes it'll use virtual memory.

Comment: Can you get some statistics on what deps you need and how big your app is?  (I'm trying to look into fixing these problems with ProGuard.)

Answer (score 3):

Use Proguard. It strips away unused classes and libraries. Link: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

EDIT:
The gc overhead limit exceeded is not because you are using proguard. Its because the memory allowed for eclipse to use is low. You can fix this by increasing the memory limit allowed (https://www.simplified.guide/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded). Do this, run proguard, and your app size will be minimal.

Comment: Please look at my comment above for Louis Wasserman. I can't able to use ProGuard. Without Proguard, my app getting build. When using ProGuard, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using open source java libraries you should first find out what licences those libraries are distributed under. Some licences do not allow you to repackage distributables other licences will only allow you to repackage if you make the new software open source (that includes your code). http://opensource.org/licenses

So after you have checked the liceneces and or contacted the rights holders.

You could write a tool that follows the dependency tree from your classes through all of your third party code and produces a list of classes that are not in that tree. I imagine most IDE's are not going to do what you want because they will consider a library as either used or not.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Mostly I am using the source classes only, not the jar. Any idea of how to read the dependency of classes? Because I am using only a small functionality of the open sources. For example I am using IText in my app, but the functionality it used for is only to merge the PDF(neither PDF creation nor PDF editing).

Comment: You can extract jars they are only zips, you can find the class files you need in the relevant packages, If you open the class file in an editor you will see that all of the import statements have been resolved to the objects, you need to ensure that all of these objects are also included. I think you will be suprised how much of the code you need. I think the best use of your effort is to get progruard working as other have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

[proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) does this for java.
From what I'm seeing it's already part of the android stack - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html .

Look at the link and try to find out why it isn't working for you (probably you aren't creating a Release build).
If it is working, and you still have a huge file, then you are probably using libraries that use a lot of files, and there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

Generate usage.txt and mapping.txt with Proguard or R8

Add `-printusage` to your proguard.pro file Run

`./gradlew app:minifyReleaseWithProguard` or `./gradlew app:minifyReleaseWithR8`

Step 2

Find class name records that is in usage.txt but not in mapping.txt, those are the unused classes that are removed by Proguard/ R8

It's not hard to write such algorithm but you can consider my approach using Java Set data structure

More details [here](https://ericntd.medium.com/find-unused-classes-in-android-codebase-c3c9fc686f4b)

Answer (score -4):

6000 classes ????? Well this is why people pay like 2000 for a compiler that removes unused code. If you put your code in eclipse it will place a yellow line under libraries, and variables that you are not using at all.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to remove the classes completely which dont have any references and no use in my Android app. Is that possible?